# My Office 365 Developer account is inactive (E5 subscription)

Tags: office365

First, a bit of background on me: I have been developing a macro-enabled Excel workbook for almost 2 years now.  It is for creating budgets for film/video projects such as TV commercials, and I released a beta version back in November.  It can be found here: www.truebudget.net

I had signed up for an Office 365 Developer account about 3 months ago, but could never login to any of my Office apps using the Developer account.  The other day I finally got someone from Microsoft Technical Support on a chat, and they were able to help me solve that problem. (Something was leftover on my computer from an old VPN I used to use that was blocking my ability to login.)  So I am finally logged in to Developer account in Excel.  Today I spend a few hours working on the next version of my Excel workbook.  However, the Developer website still says "This subscription is inactive and will expire soon. If you don't start using this subscription for development, non-admin users will lose access on Mar 22, 2020. Your subscription will be deleted on Apr 10, 2020."  I'm not sure what to do.  I used it today to write macro code in the Excel VBE, so I'm not sure what else I need to do in order to make it realize I am using it to develop for Excel.

Does anyone have any suggestions, or know of a way for me to contact someone at Microsoft about this?  I looked all around on the Developer website for a way to contact someone, but was unable to find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually takes a couple of days after you perform some development work in your tenant before it extends your free subscription out a another 100 days.  I am not sure whether your Excel work would trigger it though.  I think something has to make calls to the Graph API in your tenant, or SPFx solutions need to be deployed.  To be on the safe side, I would download some sample SPFx webparts from someone's blog that you can upload to your AppCatalog.  That should trigger the extension.

If you go to your [developer dashboard](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/profile), you should see a link there to submit an extension request if you haven't triggered the auto-extension.

Failing that, if you log in to your [Office 365 Admin portal](https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home?source=applauncher#/homepage) for your Dev Tenant, you can click on "support" and open a support request.